# LazyLoad Plugin is not willing to cooperate with my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I'm practicing to use plugins (LazyLoad at first).
According to documentation included on GitHub I've inserted lazyload class name and data-original attribute to my Pexel-pictures in html.Also added jQuery snippet. So why It doesn't work?

**HTML:**

```
<img class="lazyload" data-original="https://images.pexels.com/photos/566516/pexels-photo-566516.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/566516/pexels-photo-566516.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" width="350px"height="250">
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img.lazyload").lazyload();      
});
```

[LazyLoad docs on GitHub](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/tree/2.x)
[My code on Codepen](http://codepen.io/zeeebra/pen/EwKOdQ)

Comment: if you try to use it with the same images how can it work. The image is loaded first request.Try it with different images.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove "src" attribute value for this too work.
This link does your work [fixed code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzNMew)

```
<img class="lazyload" data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/566516/pexels-photo-566516.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb"
```

width="350px"height="250">

I did the below changes

1. removed 'src'
2. renamed 'data-original' to 'data-src'

Note: if this works for your issue, please tick this answer as answered. thanks.

Comment: @Ipradhap Thanks for answer ... but for me it works as previous. Images are "already loaded" while I want it appearing gradually from the bottom of the site during scrolling down.

Comment: Use the developer toolbar and check the images on how the lazy load works. the solution i gave you does the lazy load part. check the screencapture here. https://www.screencast.com/t/MJYmjNcBywu